# i cant use variables from controller in view (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: error]

[image: view]

**Controller**

This is the controller code:

```
$data['posts']=$this->post_model->get_posts();

$this->load->view('posts/index',$data);
```

**This is the view**

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post):?>
<h3><?php echo $post['title'];?></h3>
<small class="post-date">posted on:
<?php  echo $post['created_at'];?> </small><br>
<?php echo $post['body'];?>
<?php  endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this question is not clear enough. What exactly are you asking for? You may want to read [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does `$this->post_model->get_posts();` definitely return something? Have you done `print_r($this->post_model->get_posts())` ?

Comment: I am not sure, but i think the error is in the path to your view. If not, this might help [https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

Comment: show your directory structure

Comment: your project index file is set in development mode  ?